# UiWebView ios not using cookie in sharedHTTPCookieStorage

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies, uiwebview, afnetworking

my problem is as follows:

throughout the app to use the library Afnetworking effettura post requests to my webserver.Dopo myself authenticated by a special post request to the server I get the cookie on the request and the library Afnetworking automatically saves it in sharedHTTPCookieStorage.

As these cookies are not used automatically by the webview I wrote this method to associate the cookie with the request previously found:

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
        NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
        for (cookie in [storage cookies])
        {
            NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
            NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"mydomain"];
            if(domainRange.length > 0)
            {  NSLog(@"Cookie find for domain url");
                NSLog(@"COOKIE.VALUE = %@",cookie.value);
                NSLog(@"COOKIE = %@",cookie);
                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"my_url"]];
                //URL Requst Object

                NSMutableURLRequest *requestObj = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
               [requestObj addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cookie] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];

                return requestObj;
```

and then  [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];

but it seems that whatever cookies are not processed by the server.

I need to also use the cookie in requests to webview having previously made ​​a login in via post requests made ​​with the library afnetworking.

Thanks in advance.